# Semantic difference in translation options for the word "ring"

Tags: переклад, from-english, значення-слів

What are the differences between *"перстень"*, *"обручка"*, and *"каблучка"*? Do some of these words imply the presence of a stone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Semantically, all three are almost equivalent. СУМ: [каблучка](http://sum.in.ua/s/kabluchka), [перстень](http://sum.in.ua/s/perstenj), [обручка](http://sum.in.ua/s/obruchka). However, there are some subtle differences:

- *перстень* has been derived from Old Slavonic *перст*, "finger". The other words can (rarely) be used not only for rings, but for necklaces and other jewelry or wearings;
- *обручка* is tightly related to marriage or engagement, and these symbolize the family status of a person who wears it;
- *каблучка* is etymologically "a circle", so it denotes any object (not necessarily wearing) that has round form.

Practically, all three can be used for "a ring, with or without jewelry, both for beauty or as a symbol or marriage/engagement".

Answer (score 3):

I try to explain without words but using images:

[Перстень](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C&newwindow=1&biw=1920&bih=939&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiixIzKu4rSAhWM1ywKHXLNCvwQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=5DNOSUVpaUOHUM:)

[image]

[Каблучка](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0&newwindow=1&biw=1920&bih=939&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0x9DRu4rSAhXCkywKHWSPB5QQ_AUIBigB)

[image]

[Обручка](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0&newwindow=1&biw=1920&bih=939&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin15DXu4rSAhVHhywKHWwtBrMQ_AUIBigB)

[image]

Do you feel differences?

Comment: Looking at this picture I have the feeling that _Lord of the Rings_ should have been translated as _Володар Обручок_ :)